# how to call certain method of activity via appwidget

Tags: android

i'm trying to call a method in my main activity via a button of a widget.
the widget has different buttons with different values. i want the method to do its job without showing up the gui attached to the main activity. (send http request with button value)

so far i searched for some tutorials but i didn't quite understand them, my code got all clumsy and it barely worked. i think a mix of intents, services and broadcasts are needed to realize this?! i really don't know, can somebody post a understandable description or tutorial which covers all aspects of how to do this?
i think there is no code or pictures to provide because there is nothing look at right now.

thanks in advance for any answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Android AppWidgets don't need to have any relation at all to an `Activity`, although it is certainly possible to have a click or something *start* an activity.

As you probably know, the primary interface to AppWidgets is through your `AppWidgetProvider` (if you don't know what any of this is about, take a look at [the official android guide](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html)).

You can tell a button to use a `PendingIntent` to do one of several things when clicked:

- To start a service (probably your best option for time consuming tasks like http requests), using `PendingIntent.getService`.
- To start an activity, use `PendingIntent.getActivity`.
- To broadcast a message to a `BroadcastReceiver`, create it using `PendingIntent.getBroadcast`.

In all of these cases, you would tell the button to run the `PendingIntent` with the
`setOnClickPendingIntent(int id, PendingIntent operation)` method of `RemoteViews`.

The `Intent` you pass to any of these methods should typically be created using the `Intent(Context, Class)` constructor, where the second argument is the service, activity or receiver class you want the pending intent to be sent to.

Comment: I did it using setOnClickPendingIntent and it works like a charm. Thanks for guiding my research in the right direction. Now i can control the lights in my house via a lockscreen widget :)